# Unable to install Flow for React in Laravel project

Tags: reactjs, laravel, flowtype, laravel-mix

I am developing a Laravel application. For the front end, I am using React JS. Now I am trying to integrate Flow into my project. I followed this link https://flow.org/en/docs/install/. But not working.

I run this command in the root folder

```
npm install --save-dev babel-cli babel-preset-flow
```

Then created .babelrc file in the project root folder with the following content

```
{
  "presets": ["flow"]
}
```

Then I run this command

```
npm install --save-dev flow-bin
```

This is my package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "flow": "flow",
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
        "axios": "^0.18.0",
        "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-preset-flow": "^6.23.0",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
        "bootstrap": "^4.2.1",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "flow-bin": "^0.89.0",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.0.7",
        "lodash": "^4.17.5",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "react": "^16.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
        "react-scripts": "^2.1.2",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.15.2",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@coreui/coreui": "github:coreui/coreui",
        "@coreui/coreui-plugin-chartjs-custom-tooltips": "github:coreui/coreui-plugin-chartjs-custom-tooltips",
        "@coreui/react": "^2.1.2",
        "classnames": "^2.2.6",
        "core-js": "^2.6.1",
        "enzyme": "^3.8.0",
        "flag-icon-css": "^3.2.1",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
        "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
        "react-app-polyfill": "^0.1.3",
        "react-loadable": "^5.5.0",
        "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
        "react-router": "^4.3.1",
        "react-router-config": "^4.4.0-beta.6",
        "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
        "react-test-renderer": "^16.7.0",
        "reactstrap": "^6.5.0",
        "redux": "^4.0.1",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
        "simple-line-icons": "^2.4.1"
    }
}
```

Then I run this

```
npm run flow init
```

Then this

```
npm run flow
```

I got this error when I run the above command.

```
> @ flow /Users/wai/Desktop/easy-eat
> flow

Error ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈ vendor/symfony/translation/Tests/fixtures/empty.json:1:1

Unexpected end of input

     1│


Error ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈ vendor/symfony/translation/Tests/fixtures/malformed.json:2:11

Unexpected string

     1│ {
     2│     "foo" "bar"
     3│ }



Found 2 errors
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ flow: `flow`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ flow script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/wai/.npm/_logs/2018-12-28T21_01_36_563Z-debug.log
```

What is missing and how can I fix it?

Comment: where is the code `{ "foo" "bar" }` ?

Comment: I did not write that code at all

Comment: That's one of the two problems found. Maybe some test or dummy code somewhere. Maybe try a "find in project" in your editor for those strings?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this as well. By default Flow will check all the directories in your project. You can fix this error by creating a `.flowconfig` file in the root of your project. (Running `yarn run flow init` will also create this file for you)

Make sure to ignore the `vendor` folder through this config. My config looks like this:

```
[ignore]
.*/vendor/.*

[include]

[libs]

[lints]

[options]

[strict]
```